# Receive correct access token

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, oauth

At the moment, I try to query the Facebook Open Graph Api. 
My problem is the following:

Calling: https://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&access_token=app_id|app_secret  results in

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}
```

Also when I first receive an access token and use it, the same error appears. In the case, that I use an access token which I receive from the Graph API Explorer, everything works fine. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Comparing the access token I receive from Facebook and the access Token of the Graph API Explorer I see a difference in the length because the second token is much longer. (I think its a session token if I am not wrong)

How can I get such a token in order to do the mentioned API call?

Answer (score 0):

Your appId and secret are used to generate your access_token, they aren't actually the token so there's something wrong with your process. Some sample code might help determine where you're going wrong. Though please don't actually post your appid and secret here.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/#loginflows

You haven't stated what language you are using, but there are a number of SDKs out there already that will simplify this process.

At the bottom of the above page, there are a number of links that will walk you through the login process for different platforms so I suggest you take a look at these